# Grant privilege in oracle 12c by manual

Tags: oracle, privileges, sql-grant

I use SQL developer on Oracle 12c. I want to create a grant like

```
 GRANT  SELECT,  INSERT,  UPDATE,  DELETE ON  schema.books TO books_admin;
```

By manual. I use SQL developer  Version 4.1.4.21 . How can I do that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What do you mean by saying that you want to create it "by manual"?

Comment: Just run the statement. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQL Developer, this can be achieved with below steps ;

1. Right click on Table (to which access needs to be granted) --> Privileges --> Grant [as shown in below diagram].

[image]

2. Then assign the user & permissions to be granted [as shown in below diagram].

[image]

3. Click Apply.

Comment: Is it possible to grant select on each columns.

Comment: In that case you need to create view.
**create view view_name as select col1,col2..colN from table_name;**